# All paths of given length between two given nodes in a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

I came across this problem:

http://www.iarcs.org.in/inoi/contests/oct2005/Advanced-2.php

The problem basically is about graphs. You are given a graph with up to 70 nodes, and an adjacency matrix which tells how many edges exist between two nodes. Each edge is bidirectional.

Now the question asks you to find out the number of distinct paths OF A FIXED LENGTH N between any two nodes N1 and N2. The path can have repetitions. I.e., the path can go through an already included node.

The naivest algo is to run a breadth first search and check how many N2 appear in the Nth layer with the BFS tree rooted at N1. But this wont work.

How to go about it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution to this problem is simple - raise the adjacency matrix to the N-th power and the answer will sit in the cell `(N1, N2)` for each pair N1 and N2 - basic graph theory.

You can also make use of [binary exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) of the matrix to compute the answer faster.

To understand **why** does the above algorithm work, try to write down the first few steps of the exponentiation. You will notice that on each iteration the matrix holds the paths with a given fixed length going from 1 to N. If you write down how is a cell computed when performing matrix mutliplication you should see also why does it happen so.

NOTE: there is also a really cool hack on how do you compute all paths with length **up to** a fixed length -simply add a "loop" at the start vertex thus making it accessible from itself.

Comment: and yes, n can be as large as 10^9!

Comment: @PushkarMishra I was just adding a comment on that :) Please have a look at my edited answer. No problemo with the constraint btw. You should be able to compute that in less than a second! Take care to use a number type big enough to accommodate the answer, though

Comment: im just gonna go ahead and add that math is awesome. blows my mind

Comment: Also remember that the problem you refer to asks for the number of paths modulo 42373, so you can avoid going for really high numbers as (A*B) mod c = (A mod c)*(B mod c) also works for matrices.

Comment: @Khaur thanks for noting that I did not read the statement he linked to. You are absolutely correct if that is the case int is enough to store the answer.

Comment: Erratum: the equation should of course read "(A*B) mod c = (A mod c)*(B mod c) mod c" (extra mod at the end)

Comment: It worked! and i could make out why this works! Thank you! :D

Comment: How does the NOTE exactly work? Consider the complete graph on 3 vertices (a triangle). The adj. matrix is A=[1 1 1;1 1 1;1 1 1]. Then A*A=[3 3 3; 3 3 3;3 3 3]. But there are only two paths of length at most 2 from any vertex to any other one. (For instance 1->2 and 1->3->2). However, the result is three because with self-loops there are exactly three paths of length exactly 2 (1->1->2, 1->2->2 and 1->3->2). I don't understand how this is the same. It actually already breaks if you have only 2 vertices and ask for paths of length at most 2. There is only one such path. Your NOTE suggests 2.

Comment: @dingalapadum I tgink it's obvious that my algorithm will not work if there are loops in yhe graph.  After all if there is already a look at the start vertex adding another will not change anything. Still there was an error in my note - you only add one loop - at the start vertex,  otherwise you will have repeated routes.  Thanks for noticing

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The triangle is A=[0 1 1; 1 0 1; 1 1 0]. After adding the loops you suggested the matrix is all ones. But yes, only adding a loop at the start vertex should work I think. Nice one!